# Cannot create and attach file to an item in Podio using pypodio (PODIO API client, Python)

Tags: python, api, python-3.6, podio

I cannot seem to create and attach a file to an item in podio using the pypodio client, which is the python wrapper for PODIO's API. I am trying to get the file id but keep on getting the error. I am using Python 3.6.0

My code is

```
 `path = os.getcwd()`
 `filename="system_information"`
 `filepath = path + "\\system_information.txt"`
 `filedata=open(filepath)`
 uploading_response = pcbapp.Files.create(filename,filedata)
```

I get an error shown below, 
  File "c:\users\nipun.arora\src\podio-py\pypodio2\encode.py", line 317, in get_headers
    boundary = urllib.quote_plus(boundary)
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'quote_plus'

Answer (score 0):

That's might be because there is no `urllib.quote_plus` in python3. Can you try running same code in python2?

Comment: So there is no way we can use the Python API wrapper  to attach files in Podio if we are running python 3?